# EXFAT Patent. Is this prior art?

Tags: prior, art

I have been reading an article describing exFAT which has patents owned by Microsoft.

In the article, it also refers briefly to two sections which allegedly are patented, that being a hash of the file name (key) is used to lookup the directory entry, and the actual hash algorithm.

Hashing was used for lookups in various mainframes and minicomputers from at least the late 1970's. At the least, the Friden/Singer/ICL System Ten minicomputer using DMF II operating system supported Direct Access files which was based on hashing the lookup value (key) to locate the data. As far as I am aware, that hash algorithm was user customisable/replaceable.

In 1980/1981 ICL released a successor to the System Ten called the System 25, with DMF III as the operating system which supported Direct Access and Relative Access files. Direct Access files use a hashing algorithm to locate details in a file using the hashed result of a key.

In that year, I wrote a complete software system that made extended use of hashing a value (key) to lookup a Direct Access file which would return an address which would then be used to locate a particular data entry in another Relative Access file. For example, an Invoice Number would be hashed to lookup the address in a file where the Invoice Detail would be held.

I think that I still have microfiche of my code source from that era. I am reasonably sure I know who holds the source of at least the DMF III code.

IMHO, this seems to be the basis of the exFAT patents.

Might the DMF II and DMF III operating system, and my use of that, constitute prior art?

Comment: If you want good answers, you need to help us a little by linking to the article and patents. Since you already know where the article and hopefully patents are, it saves everyone else time searching.

Answer (score 0):

Other than a the first research on breakthrough idea, patents are much more specific than you might assume. I just searched "hash lookup key" in google patents and it says it found over 120,000 hits. To attempt to answer a question like, "Does X server as killer prior art to Y?" you need to start by having the wording of the claims of Y at hand.